# Passing array for "connect:" in noUiSlider

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, rangeslider, nouislider

I had to generate ranges and handles [**start:** and **connect:**] for `noUiSlider`. I was generating these by looping through my data from database and pushing these values to an array and use those array in `noUiSlider` option.
After generating data my code was like:

```
var start_ranges = [120,150,153,160]
var connect_val  = ["false, true, false, true, false"]
```

But when setting these as `noUiSlide` option it gave me error because of **connect_val**.

***Uncaught Error: noUiSlider (14.1.0): 'connect' option doesn't match handle count.***

My setting was something like:

```
start: start_ranges,
connect: connect_val,
range: {
       'min': 0,
       'max': 86400
       }
```

The reason was **connect_val** was string as I used`connect_val.push()` to generate dynamic settngs and it was **array** of text rather than **obejct**.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying many solutions and at last, solved the issue by the following code before setting the option for `noUiSlider`

`connect_val = JSON.parse(connect_val);`

It converted the array into object which is required by ***noUiSlider***